# GeoServer download cropped raster layer using WPS gs:download failed

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wps

I want to provide a function that allows users to download cropped raster layer stored in GeoServer on client side. For this purpose, I used GeoServer WPS gs:download process. This is the code I'm using for downloading:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wps', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
xhr.onload = function() {};
xhr.send(xmlRequest);
```

And this is the XML file I sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>gs:Download</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>layerName</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>saxony:dresden_dop</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>outputFormat</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>image/tiff</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>RoiCRS</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>EPSG:25833</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>ROI</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/wkt">&lt;![CDATA[POLYGON (( 401427.7604598588 5658195.9497047, 402604.46020956617 5658195.9497047, 402604.46020956617 5659343.11570035, 401427.7604598588 5659343.11570035, 401427.7604598588 5658195.9497047 ))]]&gt;</wps:ComplexData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
        <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/octet-stream">
            <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
        </wps:RawDataOutput>
    </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

It worked in the WPS Request Builder with the same XML file content. But it failed on the client side when I sent the request. I got the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Download Limits Exceeded. Unable to proceed!

And no matter how small the cropped region is, I always get this error.

I turned on the logging to developer, sent the request again and then got this logging messages:

> DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps.gs.download] - The underlying reader is not structured; returning native resolution
> DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps.gs.download] - Area to read in pixels: 1200000000
> DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps.gs.download] - Area exceeds the limits
> DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps.gs.download] - Download failed

It seems that the original file exceeds the limit but what I actually want to download is a small region of the original file.

Is there any way to solve this question other than changing the corresponding parameter limit?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @ianturton Hi, thanks for the reminder! I just edited and added the logging messages.

Comment: looks like you need to adjust the limits - I'm not sure if that is a WMS or WCS request or if the limit is in the downloader

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on how to setup the download limits, and configure them accordingly:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/wps-download/index.html#configuring-the-limits